# Using C# foreach tuple

Tags: c#, tuples

How can I work with tuples in a foreach loop?

The following code doesn't work:

```
foreach Tuple(x, y) in sql.lineparams(lines)
{

}
```

sql.lineparams(lines) is array of tuples `<int, string>`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What does the tuple consist of? Types called x and y? In that case, this should be your syntax:

```
foreach (Tuple<x, y> tuple in sql.lineparams(lines))
{
  ...
}
```

If the tuple actually consist of other types, like int and string, it will be like this:

```
foreach (Tuple<int, string> tuple in sql.lineparams(lines))
{
  ...
}
```

Or, you can let the compiler handle it for you:

```
foreach (var tuple in sql.lineparams(lines))
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: ahh ))) thank you , my trouble was - I forgot to use "(" after "foreach" :)

Comment: I do not know the return type of your method, so `int,string` was an example. Please let me know the actual return type of that method.

Comment: @nCdy - The solution was easier than assumed then ;)

Answer (score 18):

With C# 7 you can also directly reference the content of the tuple:

```
foreach ((x xVar, y yVar) in sql.lineparams(lines))
{

}
```